# Where is /bin/login started?

Tags: linux, sysvinit

So I'm currenly learing sysVinit. I know that at startup /bin/login has to be started in order to display a login prompt but I couldn't find a file that starts it. Is it started by default in terminals specified in inittab or what's going on there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is started by *getty* after the username is input.

1. *Init* starts /bin/agetty (or another getty) on each terminal, according to inittab
2. *Getty* initializes the terminal, shows /etc/issue and the "login:" prompt
3. User enters the login name
4. *Getty* execs /bin/login with the username as parameter
5. *Login* shows the password prompt (internal or from PAM)

(Note: *login* was also used for remote Telnet logins (although *not* by ssh logins), and the process was similar: *telnetd* would show the username prompt, and would start *login* for password prompt.)

In systemd, the process is nearly the same: *init* starts *agetty* according to `getty@<tty>.service`, and *agetty* starts *login*.